# django dajaxice javascript callback with additional parameters

Tags: javascript, callback, dajaxice

How do I go about adding extra parameters on the call back function?

eg.

```
function callback(data){
    alert(data.message);
}
```

And you would call it by `Dajaxice.examples.args_example(callback, {'text':$('#text').val()}`

what if I want to add an extra parameter in the callback function

```
function callback(data, flag){
    alert(data.message);
    if (flag){ /* do something */}
}
```

Currently I have a work around like this:

```
Dajaxice.examples.args_example(function(data){
    callback(data, true);
}, {'text':$('#text').val()});
```

Is there a better way or official way to do it in dajaxice?

Comment: I am using my workaround and it seems a good solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct to assume this flag will depend on something from within the ajax function?

If so, could you not pass your flag as a part of the returned `json`?

```
function callback(data) {
    alert(data.message);
    if (data.flag) { /* do something */}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax.py file:

```
def my_ajax_func(... my_args ...):
...
    my_message = "Hello world!"
    my_flag = True
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':my_message, 'flag':my_flag})
```

In your javascript callback function:

```
function callback(data){
    alert(data.message);
    if (data.flag){ /* do something */}
}
```